# IoT Data Model Standards

Tags: data-modeling, iot

I am currently trying to model IoT devices within buildings. I could start from scratch and develop the data model myself, but this seems like a common problem which will have been solved multiple times before. So I am looking to work from a standard.

I have found various examples including

AWS IoT Constructs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/thingsgraph/latest/ug/iot-tg-models-tdm-iot.html - models only part of the domain

Project Haystack https://project-haystack.dev/doc/index - lots of features but unsure how widely this is used

IEEE https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8389334 - not sure this is relevant as it is behind a paywall

Is there a go-to data model standard that large parts of the IoT industry uses?

Comment: Not sure why this question got instantly downvoted...?

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend third party resources are off-topic here, sorry. And no, I don't know where else you can ask for IoT standards - I would probably google for "iot discussion forum" to find a place with some experts.